# calling WordPress inbuilt functions in a custom php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use WordPress functions on a custom file but doesn't seems to be working. The file is placed in root directory. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any custom page you can call below three lines to pull up WordPress stack and then use any WordPress functionality

```
<?
    //Imp to include
    include('wp-load.php');
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('wp-blog-header.php');

    // check is user is logged - if yes then print its role
    if(is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
        echo "role is ".$role[0];

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include `wp-load.php` file at the top of the custom PHP file

```
 require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
```

**Note:** add `slashes and dots` ../../../../ as per the custom PHP file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any wordpress inbuilt function in any external file by adding `wp-load.php` file.
If your file is in the root directory. Then, you can just add following line of code on top.

```
require_once("wp-load.php");
```

For more details and example, you can visit [How to access Wordpress functions in external file](https://webolute.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-access-wordpress-functions-in-external-file)